# How to give a timeout to an FTP connection

Tags: ruby, ftp

***The story behind:***

Old script written in ruby 1.8.6 that opens a connection to a ftp and download a configuration file. For a specific client with a windows ftp server the script just hangs. The log stops writing after it opens the connection to the ftp.
It's an old script, it's in ruby and I'm not an expert on it.

***What I tried:***

So I tried this implementation of a timeout to check if an ftp connection hangs out with this code

```
Timeout::timeout(5) {
ftp = Net::FTP.new(host,pass,host)
}
```

The problem is that this isn't working. My guess is that the interpreter stops on opening the connection and the timeout doesn't kill the connection because the interpreter is stuck.

Is it possible that that's the problem?

Could you tell me if there is maybe an alternative solution or if I'm doing something wrong?

***More information about it:***

This problem happens like once in a while during a month. Like at most twice. The client sent us the ftp server logs but nothing seems wrong on that side. It's just that the FTP hangs there for no reason at all...

Comment: Sometimes things blocking like this might be DNS lookups. Have you tried to figure out what it is that is actually slowing the operation? What if you run it without the timeout and just wait..it should eventually return with an error code. But yes it is possible it's hanging when opening the connection too..

Comment: I added some info on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it hangs indefinitely. If not, the best way would be to try and capture the error code when/if it eventually times out. That would give a bit more info for analysis.

Some possible workarounds below.

#### Timeouts using `Process.fork`

However in the meantime you might switch to running the FTP task in another [**process**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html) instead, and using timeout on that. This will prevent the ruby global interpreter lock from disabling a possible timeout event like you suspect now.

Something like this:

```
child = Process.fork do
  # Run the whole FTP task in here...
  ftp = Net::FTP.new(...)
  ...
end

# Timeout handling is done in the parent process
begin
  Timeout::timeout(...) do
    Process.wait(child)
  end 
rescue Timeout::Error
  # Terminate child in case of timeout
  Process.kill("KILL", child)
end
```

#### Timeouts using `SystemTimer`

Another option, since you're running ruby 1.8.6, would be to take a look at [**SystemTimer**](http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer), which tries to get around the limitations of the ruby 1.8 `Timeout` implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to get the ftp handler to the main app? Because here's the main problem. I'm having trouble on getting this connection right? Then I have to do things with this connection that could take hours so I just need the timeout on the FTP.new method. I thought of forking but I don't know how to get the ftp connection back to the main thread.

Comment: No you can't really do that. Or..well..it IS possible to pass file descriptors from a child process to a parent process, but that's some extremely complicated low-level programming, and I'm not sure it's doable in straight ruby without additional C-extensions. Therefore I would run the whole FTP session in the forked process. You can communicate to the parent with `IO.pipe` for example if needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076257/returning-data-from-forked-processes . OR then try `SystemTimer` instead, OR switch to ruby 1.9 which should have better working `Timeout`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably going to fork a sleep and I if the main process doesn't write a tmp file, I'll kill it.