# Receiving Forked Process Output Outside Method

Tags: ruby, io, fork, ipc

I'm new to `ruby` and object oriented languages, and I'm having trouble figuring out a way to accomplish forking a process inside a method and passing the delayed output to be used outside the method while also returning the process id.

```
def method(arg)
    proc_id = fork do
        var = `command #{arg}`
    end
    return both = [proc_id, var]
end
```

This doesn't work as `var` will return `nil` since the process has not yet finished.  How could I accomplish something like this?

UPDATE:

Using `IO.pipe` I was able to accomplish Inter-Process Communication.  However, trying to use this solution inside a method will not allow me to return both `proc_id` and `var` without first waiting for the process to finish which forces me to create new arrays and iterations that would be otherwise unnecessary.  The objective here is to have freedom to execute code outside the method while the `fork` process inside the method is still working.

```
arg_array = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"]
input = []
output = []
proc_id = []
arg_array.each_index do |i|
    input[i], output[i] = IO.pipe
    proc_id[i] = fork do
        input[i].close
        output[i].write `command #{arg_array[i]}`
    end
    output[i].close
end
command2
command3
include Process
waitpid(proc_id[0])
command4
Process.waitall
arg_array.each_index do |x|
    puts input[x].read
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning data from forked processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076257/returning-data-from-forked-processes)

Comment: If you really want learn the concept, read this http://www.jstorimer.com/products/working-with-unix-processes

Comment: @sawa I've updated to show this is a bit different as I'm trying to pass both the process id and the output of the `fork` to be used outside the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **jaeheung**'s suggestion, I've solved using `Open3.popen2` (requires version 1.9.3).

```
arguments = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4"]
require 'open3'
include Open3
def method(arg)
    input, output, thread = Open3.popen2("command #{arg}")
    input.close
    return [thread.pid, output]
end
thread_output = []
arguments.each do |i|
    thread_output << method("#{i}")
end
command1
command2
include Process
waitpid(thread_output[0][0])
command3
Process.waitall
thread_output.each do |x|
    puts x[1].read
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a little more time studying the concept of fork. The parent and child process after a fork cannot communicate (exchange variables) each other without using IPC (Inter-Processs Communication) which is somewhat complicated.

But for your purpose (getting the child process id, and its output), it's easier with Open3.popen2 or Open3.popen3.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2

Answer (score 0):

if you want to kick something off and save the child pid, that's fairly simple.

```
pid = fork
if pid
    return pid
else
    system("command #{arg}")
    exit
end
```

a little bit clumsy, but basically, `fork` returns the child pid to the parent process, and `nil` to the child process.  Make sure you exit the child, it won't do that automatically.

Comment: I need to `fork` and return the process id.

Comment: That's a different animal then.  You may want to make that clearer in your question.

Comment: Changed my answer, that might help you more.