# Process stucks when invoke childprocess from a forked process in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, process, multiprocessing, fork

The following code stucks in MRI 1.9.3 but seems to work in 2.0.0 and 2.1.2.

```
def run_in_isolation
  # From http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076445/841064
  read, write = IO.pipe

  pid = fork do
    read.close
    result = yield
    Marshal.dump(result, write)
    exit
  end

  write.close
  result = read.read
  Process.wait(pid)
  raise 'child failed' if result.empty?
  Marshal.load(result)
end

run_in_isolation do
  require 'childprocess' # http://rubygems.org/gems/childprocess
  process = ChildProcess.build("ruby", "-e", "sleep")
  process.start
end
```

Why? And how can I make it working in 1.9.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. You're trying to `Marshal.load` a ChildProcess process, i.e. the return value from `process.start` in the parent where ChildProcess was never loaded. Since the module (`ChildProcess`) does not exist in the parent process, this will raise an ArgumentError on any Ruby version.
2. On 1.9, the write side of the created pipe will be inherited by the sleeping Ruby process started through `ChildProcess`. Since the write side isn't closed, the `read()` call will hang. In Ruby 2.X, the default behaviour was changed so that non-standard file descriptors are closed on `exec`. To solve this (in a cross-platform way) you can call `ChildProcess.close_on_exec(write)` just before you yield.